# Use of Selenium for AngularJS based Web Applications

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, nightwatch.js

I have come to know that Selenium is the father of UI testing.

Now my question is why then Angular team has developed Protractor. Can't the same job (that Protractor does) be done with Selenium for AngularJS based web applications?

Further, people are talking about Nightwatch.js too. So why there are so many E2E testing libraries/frameworks like Protracor or Nightwatch.

Comment: Protractor is not a replacement of Selenium webdriver but relies on it to run tests atop. More info: http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/server-setup

Comment: @codef0rmer my question is why do you need Protractor in the first place if Selenium can do the same work.

Comment: I shared the link because they have pretty much explained what role protractor plays in the setup. More info: http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/infrastructure

Comment: Is there anyone who is using Nightwatch.js?

Comment: There are problems when you try to use Selenium web-driver for Angular UI apps. At least I have encountered such problems when elements which are in DOM are not accessible through standard web-driver techniques like retrieval by xpath or by id. After review of few already posted questions on stackoverflow I found out that I am not alone in having such problems and that there are really no answers how to handle Angular UI by web-driver.

Answer (score 9):

Protractor combines powerful tools and technologies such as NodeJS, Selenium, webDriver, Jasmine, Cucumber and Mocha. Has a bunch of customizations from Selenium to easily create tests for AngularJS applications. Speeds up your testing as it avoids the need for a lot of “sleeps” and “waits” in your tests, as it optimizes sleep and wait times. Allows tests to be organized based on Jasmine, thus allowing you to write both unit and functional tests on Jasmine. It runs on real browsers and headless browsers...

You can find all these information here => http://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/testing-angularjs-apps-protractor.

Answer (score 2):

Protractor also provides you to wait for scope changes using `protractor.waitForAngular()` which I think may or may not be implemented using Selenium. You'll still have to bang around your head in order simulate the same feature using selenium.

**My opinion**

If you just want to do UI testing and not interested in listening for `scope` changes or any `angular` specific events, you can go ahead with selenium. But it's a HUGE advantage using Protractor for e2e tests for Angular.

Comment: What is the huge advantage of Protractor over Selenium Webdriver?