# Compatibility of Selenium with AngularJS 2.0

Tags: angular, selenium

We are going to migrate our UI to AngularJS 2.0 once it is released to market.
So wanted to know about compatibility of Selenium with AngularJS 2.0?

Thanks,
Rupesh

Comment: Selenium doesn't depend upon any JavaScript frameworks, it depend upon your browser what you are using...

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062969/testing-angularjs-with-selenium, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033901/use-of-selenium-for-angularjs-based-web-applications